# Google Sheets: Script to Look for Last Value in Column and Add to Another Cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Good morning kind stack overflow users. I am new to Google Apps Scripts and am working on a tool that my wife and I use for budgeting purposes.

I have been able to create a script that will copy a row with formatting and values however I am looking for a way to take my script one step further. I have not been able to find any information that will help me along this path and I was hoping to gain some knowledge from this community.

My goal is to automatically add two cells together based on the last cell that has values in a column. Please see below screenshot for more information.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jtsx2.jpg)

Comment: See `Sheet#getRange`, `Range#getValues`. Then use a for loop to iterate the array of values, bottom to top, and check for the next non-empty cell.

Comment: we can't help you if you if you didn't try anything yet

Comment: Thank you tehhowch, with respect Liora, I have been looking for information... My scripting is limited and next to none, but I will work on the for loop to make that work.

Answer (score 0):

It's always best to LINK to your spreadsheet (or a copy of it without sensitive data), so this wont' be an exact re-creation of the spreadsheet you provided, but in principle, this should do what I believe you need based on your unclear description:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1e09vy60VTQH782WJWGT3kwDxx79XNmta_HCa7ags-C4/edit?usp=sharing

Assuming you have data with a different number of rows 2-9, and your static row on row 10, then the formula for Cell A11 should look like this:

```
=index(A2:A9,count(A2:A9))+A10
```

Keep in mind, this will only work if there are not blank cells above the last row with a value.